# Is this a hardware or software failure?

Tags: hardware, crash, motherboard

My system freezes up increasingly, but tests show nothing for HDD, SSD, RAM and it runs fine from a live CD. Given the details below, what does this point to, or what else can I test?

I ran Ubuntu 14.04 on a ThinkPad t440s (Intel graphics) for quite a while, on a mydigital supercache 2 64G SSD firmware 1.6.

After I got some freezes recently, I figured maybe the SSD is dying, so I did a fresh Ubuntu 14.04 install to a HDD partition, also the swap from SSD cryptswap to HDD normal swap (deleted crypttab and fstab lines).

But on the new OS, with the SSD removed, the system still increasingly crashes, giving me kernel panics, soft lockups, etc. upon login. It runs if I stick to the terminal though.

Memtest-ing the system from a live medium gives me no ram errors, but it always gets stuck on boot trail at '507 1st Barr'. 
Using Disk from a live CD gives me no errors for the HDD on extended tests of all partitions. 
The system runs fine from the live CD, also when cranking up CPU load by using `cat /dev/zeros > /dev/null` and/or similar.

Does the live USB use the motherboard or some other component differently that would explain why it works but the 'internal' systems (from HDD or SSD) don't?

Update: It froze on me from the live CD yesterday also, so I guess this is going fast towards hardware failure. I will give it to service and see what they say.

Comment: Sounds like a thermal issue.  Can you check the heat sensors from the Live session?

Comment: Well, the disk utility (I think its Smartmontools) from the live session gives 43 for the harddisk. When being able to login for a minute before freezing, Psensor gives me around 55 for both CPUs.

Comment: Can you get the same information on an HDD-booted session (before it freezes)?  I bet the CPU is running hotter...

Comment: sorry that wasn't clear,  I only have Psensor installed on the HDD-based Ubuntu, which does freeze on my, but when I open sensors first thing after logging in, the CPU's are at that temperature, about 55 degrees.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although it would have been interesting to know if I could have found out by system tests myself, the quick answer is: it was a hardware failure.

Why? Because the technical service replaced my motherboard. That convinces me; luckily it was still on warranty.